# Server software for collaborative math?

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, math

I have recently registered a mathematics-related domain for collaborative problem-solving and proof-development. Features I would need:

1. basic user account control;
2. MathML or MathJAX or similar (obviously);
3. single-document multi-author support (similar to SubEthaEdit or GoogleDocs):
4. versioning (like Wikipedia);
5. post threading and searching (like SE forums).

Other features would be nice to have, but I can't think of any more that would be absolutely essential.

Most software I have found in my research is non-math collaborative software (e.g., for simple text documents), or too single-purpose (e.g., SageMathCloud).

What [server] software packages are available to host a collaborative mathematics environment? What are the pros/cons of each?

Comment: What features do you need?

Comment: I would need at least:
1. basic user account control;
2. full MathML or MathJAX or similar (obviously);
3. single-document multi-author support (like SubEthaEdit or GoogleDocs):
4. versioning (like Wikipedia);
5. post threading and searching (like SE forums).

Other features would be nice to have, but I can't think of any more that would be absolutely essential.

Comment: Could you please paste this to the body of your question? Comments tends to get ignored and deleted. Thanks!